# How to show current location (the green dot) on MapField in Blackberry Java SDK

Tags: blackberry, java-me, maps, blackberry-maps

Here's the frustrating problem.

As you know, we can use `net.rim.device.api.lbs.maps.ui.RichMapField` in blackberry api to integrate the map feature into our mobile application.

So I use it in my application. The RichMapField works fine, as I can see streets and roads, I just can't see where i am in the map - There should be a green/blue dot that represents where I am. And the GPS icon at the top left corner shouldn't have a red cross on it.

The GPS icon with a red cross on it means no GPS signals.

But I am pretty sure I got the GPS signals as my current location showed up on the official Blackberry Map App (Got a green dot that represents where I am and the GPS icon on the left top corner of the screen does not have the red cross).

And by the way, in official Blackberry Map App, everything works good (there's a green dot that represents where I am on the map and no red cross on the GPS icon at the left top corner of the screen).

The question is:
How to make the GPS active with RichMapField and show my current location as a green dot on the map just like how the official Blackberry Map App does when I use the `RichMapField` in my app?

Below is more information:
I have tried using `BlackBerryLocationProvider` to fetch GPS data. and it works. but that does not remove the red cross from the GPS icon on the `RichMapField` and the green dot (current location) does not show up. I just can change the center of the map with returned lat/longi

```
action.setCentre(new MapPoint(location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude(),
                              location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude()));
```

Do I need to add a special location listener to `BlackBerryLocationProvider`?

Comment: I guess you can access BlackBerry maps only on BIS or BES. You cannot load BlackBerry maps on Wifi or GPRS (mobile data package).

Comment: Thanks for reply. The RichMapField works, I can see streets and roads. I mean the terms of the GPS icon with a red cross on it (at the left top corner). I want to see where I am on the Map. There should be a green or blue dot that represents me.

Comment: oh ok. I am actually using google maps and the marker on the current location is created through an html tag. The marker image is placed in the img folder which the html tag refers to. Have you provided any such marker?

Comment: Are you using webwork? Applications based on webwork have a restrict on the max amount of memory occupation . and google map is quite a memory consuming lib...

Comment: No I am not using webworks. I am basically fetching the current location through GPS and passing those coordinates into a html tag that I create for the map.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/Custom_maps_1227238_11.jsp

Comment: Hi Mister, I went through all documents at here http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/Custom_maps_1227238_11.jsp that is the link you sent me. none of them mentioned showing current location as a green dot on the map....

Comment: Hi Sarah, when you said 'a html tag', Did you refer to BrowserField?

Comment: @Lewisou I think the "current location green mark" is just a regular placemark. If you readed the whole series then you'll have readed this one for sure. Anyway, here it is: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17954/Tagging_locations_on_a_map_1205323_11.jsp